# Philishave (Norelco) HS550 reverse-engineering

Tags: circuit-analysis, reverse-engineering

My first question here. Image is schematic for Philishave (Norelco in US) HS550 shaver - 110V-230VAC.

[image: schematic]

I am puzzled how this works.

I think that on the early part of the positive half cycle the supply is routed to OUT+ via D2, and Q1 is switched on via C1 (with base voltage limited by D3), and when the voltage exceeds a limit (probably somewhat over 120V) Q2 will turn Q1 off (with Q2 base drive via R12/D4/D5/D6/R10).

R1 is probably to limit inrush, and runs pretty warm.

But I cannot fathom the purpose of R3.
Or R2.
Nor the parallel R7 and R8 pair (and why not use a single 0R47 or similar?).
Nor D7 and R11.
Nor R5 (which looks like 1/4W?).

D1 is integral to Q1.

D6 is unknown, but tests as a diode. This has two colour bands, brown and grey, on a black background. It does not test as either a 1.8V or 18V zener (took it up to 29V with series 1k), but may be defective.

The shaver is faulty, with the motor speed changing (speeding up for a few seconds, then slowing until almost stopped, repeating). But Q1 (BU724AS) measures with a hFE of about 45 when specs for this is > 1000, so...

(Q2 - BC547 - seems to be fine.)

Any thoughts?

Comment: yes .... what is your question?

Comment: Have you tried simulating it?

Comment: BU724A datasheet http://www.datasheet.es/download.php?id=731338

Comment: As @winny said, you may simulate is using LTspice (which is the most famous) or any other similar schematic simulator

Comment: Check your circuit again.  The part you label R4 is a PTC fuse.  You wouldn't put a fuse across the input lines like that... it should be in series.   That part might be a capacitor if you have the wiring correct

Comment: R2 would be discharging R4 ( because that's probably a capacitor).  R4 as a capacitor is for electromagnetic noise reduction.  R2 Keeps you from getting a mild 220v shock when touching the plug if R4 happens to be charged.

Comment: Hi Winny. No I don't have the skills to simulate this circuit.

Comment: Hi Bruce. Thank you for that datasheet. (I wonder if these are still available, or if there is a modern 850V equivalent).

Comment: Hi Kyle. I think the part I (or rather Eagle) labelled R4 is a transient suppressor. It is labelled 593-PH 460V. I think the 'PH' part signifies Philips.

Comment: Hi Kyle. Would a 1 Ohm resistor protect from a 230V shock? But I think you are correct about the 470k R2 - this would be to discharge the circuit, particularly C1, wouldn't it?